# DropDown Value Incremented one in every entry in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I want in gridview every entry corresponding  value increment in dropdown

I want every corresponding entry dropdown value increment

if one row inserted in grid then In dropdown it show 1 and 2 continuous...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdBandlevel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="band_level_id" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="4"
       OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdBandlevel_RowCancelingEdit" 
       OnRowEditing="GrdBandlevel_RowEditing" 
         OnRowUpdating="GrdBandlevel_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="GrdBandlevel_RowCommand"
       ShowFooter="True" OnRowDeleting="GrdBandlevel_RowDeleting" 
            onpageindexchanging="GrdBandlevel_PageIndexChanging" 
        ondatabound="GrdBandlevel_DataBound" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#D1B271" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="4" onrowdatabound="GrdBandlevel_RowDataBound"
        >
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" BorderColor="#D1B271" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000000"  BorderColor="#D1B271"/>
       <Columns>

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BandLevel Name" SortExpression="Location_name">
               <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("band_level_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ValidationGroup="update"
                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Please enter bandlevelName">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
               </EditItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqNewname" runat="server" ValidationGroup="save"
                            ControlToValidate="txtNewName" ErrorMessage="Please enter ResourceName">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
               </FooterTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("band_level_name") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>



            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sorting">
               <EditItemTemplate>

                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSorting" runat="server" DataTextField="Sorting" DataValueField="band_level_id"
>             


                   </asp:DropDownList>
               </EditItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate>

                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewSorting" runat="server"  >

                   </asp:DropDownList>
               </FooterTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblSorting" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sorting") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ShowHeader="False">
               <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                       Text="Update" ValidationGroup="update"></asp:LinkButton>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                       Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
               </EditItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="AddNew"
                            Text="Add New" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:LinkButton>
               </FooterTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                       Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:CommandField HeaderText="" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True"  />

       </Columns>
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#D1B271" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" BorderColor="#D1B271" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#D1B271" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000000" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#D1B271"/>
       <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <PagerTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </PagerTemplate>

   </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I Have two column in gridview One is name and second is Level i want in grid if no entry in dropdown it shows 1 and in second entry dropdown shows 1 and two ans so on..

Comment: Please take more care on your questions. It is still not clear how your GridView looks like(what TemplateFields,BoundFields,DataSource,Events,...). Where is this mysterious DropDownList?

Comment: I edit the question Please see it

Comment: You should better tell us which function the DropDownList has, because it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Is the Ddl for sorting? Are you asking only for the footer-ddl? Then you only need to count the rows of your DataSource.